# Font is not loading when using styled-components with react and storybook

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, storybook

I'm building app based on React, Typescript with build on Webpack. So basically everything is working ok when using `webpack` or `webpack-dev-server`. But then I wanted to use storybook, and I want to put some fonts that are inside my project directory. And in sotrybook I can't see my fonts, they're not working for some reason - I think that could be webpack related.

I'm using this to load fonts:

```js
//globalStyle.ts
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import bender from "../resources/fonts/Bender.otf";

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bender';
    src: url(${bender});
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

So using this in code as `<GlobalStyle/>` with default webpack build is working. But to apply the effect for each story-book component I use this decorator:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import GlobalStyle from "../src/styles/globalStyle";
import mainTheme from "../src/styles/mainTheme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { configure, addDecorator } from "@storybook/react";

const req = require.context("../src/", true, /\.stories\.tsx$/);

function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

const withGlobal = storyFn => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      {storyFn()}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

addDecorator(withGlobal);
configure(loadStories, module);
```

Going to the story-book inspector I see that style has loaded, but looking at `@font-face` fields i see something like

```
@font-face {
src: url()
/**/
}
```

So the URL of font is empty. I tried replacing in my code this `import` to `require(_path_)` and the `src: url()` was filled but then no file under this address.

I am using custom storybook webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.tsx'],
    addons: ['@storybook/preset-typescript'],
    webpackFinal: async config => {
        config.module.rules.push(
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                use:
                    [
                        { loader: require.resolve('ts-loader') },
                        { loader: require.resolve('react-docgen-typescript-loader') },
                    ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
                    },
                ],
            },
        );
        config.output.publicPath = "http://localhost:9001/"
        config.resolve.extensions.push('.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx');
        return config;
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you console log `${bender}` in your `globalStyle.ts`? Also, why not set the  `@font-face` url directly instead of `src: url(${bender});`?

Comment: @eMontielG tried that and it was `undefined` What do you mean by that? Like that `src: ${benderBlack};`?

Comment: I mean `src: url(../resources/fonts/Bender.otf);`.

Comment: Okay, so basically I've moved my resources folder outside `src` to `public`. And then applied that. It's working in Storybook and `webpack-dev-server`. Thanks for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue because my font wasn't being downloaded so I added the font link to a file `preview-head.html` inside `.storybook` folder.

Check https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/add-custom-head-tags/